# JAVA, Android Development

Tags: java, android

I have to add listener to button widget which can change Text in Edit Text Box but compiler is giving error for syntax of `setText`.

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text1.setText("Please go"); // compiler shows the error here
});
```

Comment: Your code that sets the text should be inside the method `onClick(View v)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have some missing brackets in the onClick

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text1.setText("Please go");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text1.setText("Please go");
        }
    });
```